# Why are they fighting each other?

Tags: foiled

So I was playing Foiled for a while and then switched to something else for a while. When I came back Gold was backed up against a wall and Red was repeatedly hitting him with no success. Is this one of those "neglect" things where it returns to this after not playing for a certain amount of time, or did I accidently press the keys down like that for a while and they stuck that way or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever key you had pressed when you switched windows probably didn't register the release, so when you switched back it still thinks that key is pressed.  This is pretty common in a lot of applications.